# Javascript to redirect URL not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an `iframe` reference on my site with `src=https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do?`. However, I want to have the Javascript that handles creating the URL `http://www.crossmatch.com/jobs?jobPostingID=100135` to redirect to `https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do?jobPostingID=100135` this will be invisible and seamless to the applicant.

I have created the code below, but the redirect is not happening.

```
<iframe id="careersiframe" src="https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do?" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1"
    style="position:absolute;top:100px;width:800px;height:400px;border:solid 1 px">
</iframe>
```

This is the script I wrote to redirect the end user:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('careersiframe').src = "https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do" + window.location.search;
</script>
```

Comment: As a side note, the `language` attribute is deprecated and no longer used. If you want to specify a type, use `type="text/javascript"`. Keep in mind though that with HTML5, this attribute is no longer required...

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the iframe after changing `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('careersiframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems right; however, there must be something else here at play. My first guess is that the issue is that you're using HTTPS in your iframe, which is a different domain (hgncloud.com) than the parent page (crossmatch.com). This is causing a **cross-origin** request.

If you have access to the code on crossmatch.com, I would recommend updating that to do a server redirect. It's really the best option for any redirect because you bypass the browser's security concerns. You will want to send an HTTP 301 or 307 request depending on your specific needs. Sending this is dependent on the server side programming language.

Still having issues? Remember, the issue could be something else. If you post more code or any errors you are seeing, we will be able to help better.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree. My answer is that it is a cross origin issue. My solution is to do a server redirect.